# Number of fog droplets in the air

Tags: visible-light, water, volume, mean-free-path

I have an issue with the official solution to this problem from BelPhO:

> Visibility on the road is 100 m. Assuming that the diameter of a fog
> droplet is 1 micron, estimate the concentration of fog droplets in the
> air.

The official solution is:

> If a drop of water gets in the way of a photon, the photon will be
> scattered or absorbed. To estimate the average "flight" length of a
> photon, the following reasoning can be carried out: in cylinder of
> diameter equal to the diameter equal to the diameter of the droplet
> and length equal to the free span on average there should be one
> droplet, i.e.
>
> $$l \frac{\pi d^2}{4} n \approx 1 \Rightarrow n \approx \frac{4}{\pi d^2 l} \approx \frac{4}{\pi(10^{-6})^2 \cdot 100} \approx 10^{10} \mathrm{m}^{-3}$$

I cannot see how this physical situation described by the solution can best fit the model of the initial problem. The only information we are given is the visible radius $l$ and the size of a droplet. Do you not think (as I think) that the solution admits the **untrue assumption** that the visibility distance is equal to the mean free path?
Doesn't it seem more reasonable to you that the fraction of the surface of a sphere of diameter $d$ which is obscured depends directly on the number of droplets within the visible radius, which is something proportional to the concentration $n$ of the fog droplet times a volume?

Any advice or detailed explanation is appreciated. Please let me know what you think. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Well the easiest solution is to say $L$ is inversely proportional to $n$ and $d^2$, so:

$$ \frac 1 L \propto nd^2$$

or:

$$ n \approx \frac 1 {d^2L} = 10^{10}\,{\rm m^{-3}}$$

and be done.

A more serious attempt is to consider the extinction of out going photons with a number density of $N(r)$:

$$ \frac{dN}{dr} = -\frac {da} A $$

where (using capitals for lengths for clarity):

$$ da = n dV \pi D^2$$

is the area covered at radius $r$ by the number of particles in the shell:

$$ dV = n(4\pi r^2 dr) $$

and

$$ A = 4\pi r^2 $$

is the total area of a shell at radius $r$.

So:

$$ \frac{dN}{dr} = -\frac{\pi D^2} 4 $$

which has a solution:

$$ N(r) = N_0e^{-r/L} $$

with

$$ L = \frac 4 {\pi D^2 n} $$

which is exactly with the cylinder argument gives.

The cylinder argument works because the $4\pi$'s in $dV$ and $A$ cancel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. A spherical fog droplet of radius $a$ blocks an area $\pi a^2$ from view. If the volume concentration of droplets is $C$, then the amount of fog droplets in a spherical shell of radius $r$ and thickness $\mathrm{d}r$ is $4\pi Cr^2\,\mathrm{d} r$, and the total area they block from view is (at most) $4C\pi^2a^2 r^2\,\mathrm{d} r$. We could find $n$ from the requirement that the droplets within a sphere of radius $l = 100 \ \mathrm{m}$ entirely block the surface area of that sphere from view. The result would be different. Why isn't this right?

Comment: @bml You can never guarantee that the view is *entirely* blocked by droplets, because the droplets are distributed randomly. There is always a finite (if negligible) probability of a clear path of any distance. This is why we talk about the mean free path instead of an absolute limit.